# NullPointerException thrown by Charset.availableCharsets due to our Sybase JDBC driver

Tags: jdbc, character-encoding, nullpointerexception, sybase, sap-ase

I am running into a **blocking issue** with my install (JDK 1.7). Basically I have the following NPE:

```
10:19:17.548 [main] ERROR o.s.t.w.s.TestDispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1007) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:289) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.createDefaultStrategy(DispatcherServlet.java:810) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getDefaultStrategies(DispatcherServlet.java:779) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initHandlerAdapters(DispatcherServlet.java:587) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initStrategies(DispatcherServlet.java:444) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.onRefresh(DispatcherServlet.java:432) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:525) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136) [spring-webmvc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160) [tomcat-servlet-api-7.0.37.jar:3.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvcBuilderSupport.createMockMvc(MockMvcBuilderSupport.java:53) [spring-test-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.DefaultMockMvcBuilder.build(DefaultMockMvcBuilder.java:207) [spring-test-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.mycompany.ui.controller.ConnectionInfosControllerTest.setup(ConnectionInfosControllerTest.java:41) [test-classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74) [spring-test-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83) [spring-test-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72) [spring-test-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231) [spring-test-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88) [spring-test-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71) [spring-test-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174) [spring-test-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197) [.cp/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1000) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.put(Charset.java:550) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.access$300(Charset.java:276) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
    at java.nio.charset.Charset$4.run(Charset.java:593) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
    at java.nio.charset.Charset$4.run(Charset.java:585) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.availableCharsets(Charset.java:584) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.<init>(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:66) ~[spring-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.<init>(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:56) ~[spring-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.<init>(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:201) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
```

I strongly suspect it is related to the following bug: [see report here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6907974)

I am desperately **looking for a workaround**. Note that I haven't touched the jdk installation. I haven't added or removed any charset...

Can anyone help?

**edit 1**: See other bug report [here](http://mailing.freebsd.java.narkive.com/2k7D2HeF/nullpointerexception-in-charset-java-493) and notice the "for some reason"...

**edit 2**: I have further info regarding the above issue: I have added the following test case **in a separate project**:

```
package pack;

import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

public class TestCase {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set set = Charset.availableCharsets().keySet();
        for (Iterator iterator = set.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            String s = (String) iterator.next();
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

I noticed that the test case **runs without any error**!

Now when I add the **very same test case to our project** (built with maven), I run into the same NPE:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.put(Charset.java:550)
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.access$300(Charset.java:276)
    at java.nio.charset.Charset$4.run(Charset.java:593)
    at java.nio.charset.Charset$4.run(Charset.java:585)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.availableCharsets(Charset.java:584)
    at pack.TestCase.main(TestCase.java:9)
```

I therefore suspect it might be **related to our config of maven**. Any one has any clue of what could cause this Charset issue in a **multimodule maven config**?

**edit 3**:
The effective POM is too long. Here is the pastebin for it: [pastebin here](http://pastebin.com/bdiV8QUf)

**edit 4**:
I managed to pinpoint the problematic dependency. Here it is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sybase</groupId>
    <artifactId>jconn4</artifactId>
    <version>7.07.GA</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

By removing this dependency, the TestCase executes properly and prints out all available charsets. However, we do need a database driver for our app. Any one has got any clue as to what is going wrong with sybase jdbc driver?

Comment: If you strongly suspect that it might be related to your maven config, it might be worth showing us what that config looks like.

Comment: Also, it would help if you could provide the source code for the spring bean (at least the constructor that's failing). Are you sure you are mocking the dependencies correctly?

Comment: @rimero I have added a pastebin of the effective pom.

Comment: @Vegard Note that the testcase fails without any spring bean being instanciated.

Comment: Gone from Spring for a while. The error happened in `StringHttpMessageConverter`, so maybe somewhere a charset is expected and something else is given (a language?). Maybe search the beans.

Comment: @JoopEggen Thanks! I actually managed to isolate the issue (see edit 2) and therefore I am 100% positive this has got nothing to do with Spring (beans). The issue is that `availableCharsets` throws a NPE given our current maven config.

Comment: @all see edit 4: this is a sybase jdbc issue... I am not sure how to sort it though.

Comment: I'm seeing this same issue, but do not have the Sybase driver.  Anyone have any thoughts how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out to be a **bug in the Sybase JDBC driver** as one can see [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/jtds/bugs/692/). To quote the disgruntled user of the Sybase JDBC driver from the above link:

> Nothing should suprise me though, as the current Sybase driver is
>   utterly broken, and has been for over a year! It contains a
>   CharsetProvider, that returns a null iterator causing
>   Charset.availableCharsets() to throw a nullpointer exception. A lot of
>   frameworks such as Spring calls Charset.availableCharsets().

I am not sure how to report this bug to Sybase/SAP though...

Comment: If you have a Sybase support contract, you should be able to report the bug by calling support.

Comment: In case it helps anyone I was getting the error with jconn4 7.07 but not jconn4 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if anyone still looking for the answer or not...But yes, this is a bug in Sybase driver jar. There is a discussion and solution within this link [Discussion of NPE with jconn4.jar in SAP](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3372589). I just faced the same issue and got resolved by replacing with a newer jar(it turned out we were using the very old one.)