# NullPointerException thrown with Spring boot application when jconn4.jar is added in the build path

Tags: spring-boot, sybase, jconnect

I'm new to Spring boot and I'm trying to use it to develop a web application.As I need to connect to a Sybase database in my app, I have to include jconn4.jar in my build path. However I keep getting below NullPointerException right after I added the jconn4.jar to my build path.

```
2016-09-30 14:15:48.116  INFO 74768 --- [           main] m.j.a.SpringBootPractice          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-09-30 14:15:48.116 DEBUG 74768 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Loading source class main.java.appstarter.SpringBootPractice
2016-09-30 14:15:48.160  INFO 74768 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1a1e9a9: startup date [Fri Sep 30 14:15:48 EDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-09-30 14:15:48.162 DEBUG 74768 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Bean factory for org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1a1e9a9: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@10ee7e5: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory,SpringBootPractice]; root of factory hierarchy
2016-09-30 14:15:48.975 DEBUG 74768 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.AutoConfigurationPackages        : @EnableAutoConfiguration was declared on a class in the package 'main.java.appstarter'. Automatic @Repository and @Entity scanning is enabled.
2016-09-30 14:15:49.252  INFO 74768 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d55d155b] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-09-30 14:15:49.291 DEBUG 74768 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Unable to locate MessageSource with name 'messageSource': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DelegatingMessageSource@8bdbd8]
2016-09-30 14:15:49.291 DEBUG 74768 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Unable to locate ApplicationEventMulticaster with name 'applicationEventMulticaster': using default [org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster@145e7b9]
2016-09-30 14:15:49.622 DEBUG 74768 --- [           main] .t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory : Code archive: C:\Users\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\1.4.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar
2016-09-30 14:15:49.622 DEBUG 74768 --- [           main] .t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory : Code archive: C:\Users\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\1.4.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar
2016-09-30 14:15:49.623 DEBUG 74768 --- [           main] .t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory : None of the document roots [src/main/webapp, public, static] point to a directory and will be ignored.
2016-09-30 14:15:49.656  WARN 74768 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
2016-09-30 14:15:49.664 ERROR 74768 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:535) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at main.java.appstarter.SpringBootPractice.main(SpringBootPractice.java:19) [bin/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.URLDecode(UDecoder.java:352) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.URLDecode(UDecoder.java:324) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3113) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.addServletMapping(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:277) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.addDefaultServlet(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:257) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.prepareContext(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:213) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:176) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at java.nio.charset.Charset.put(Charset.java:538) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
at java.nio.charset.Charset.access$200(Charset.java:271) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
at java.nio.charset.Charset$3.run(Charset.java:584) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
at java.nio.charset.Charset$3.run(Charset.java:573) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
at java.nio.charset.Charset.availableCharsets(Charset.java:572) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.B2CConverter.<clinit>(B2CConverter.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
... 17 common frames omitted
```

I've been searching over all related q/a and found one possible reason for this in below link:[NullPointerException thrown by Charset.availableCharsets due to our Sybase JDBC driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979586/nullpointerexception-thrown-by-charset-availablecharsets-due-to-our-sybase-jdbc)

But I don't see anyone suggesting any solutions for this.

I've been trying a lot of possibilities but still this exception occurs as long as it's added to the build path. This is stopping me from progressing any more.

Below is my pox.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

Configurations for database

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver
```

Could anyone help me on this or give any suggestions how could I proceed?

Any input will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like no one is answering my question. I just got an answer from this link[NullPointerException thrown by...](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3372589). It turned out I was using the jconn4.jar from 2012. I've replaced it with a new one from 2013 and the exception is gone.