# Factory method 'stringHttpMessageConverter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: spring, http, spring-boot

I am using Springboot + Spring JPA in my stanalone application. But i am geeting following error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
>   Failed to instantiate
>   [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter]:
>   Factory method 'stringHttpMessageConverter' threw exception; nested
>   exception is java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
>     ... 69 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   java.nio.charset.Charset.put(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.nio.charset.Charset.access$200(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.nio.charset.Charset$3.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.nio.charset.Charset$3.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.nio.charset.Charset.availableCharsets(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:67)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration$StringHttpMessageConverterConfiguration.stringHttpMessageConverter(HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.java:77)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration$StringHttpMessageConverterConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4ce1453d.CGLIB$stringHttpMessageConverter$0()
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration$StringHttpMessageConverterConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4ce1453d$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1235f10b.invoke()
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration$StringHttpMessageConverterConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4ce1453d.stringHttpMessageConverter()
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
>     ... 70 more

My Config class as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {
        "com.automation.entity"
})
public class DataAccessPersistenceContext {

    @Bean
    public DataSource sybaseDataSource() {
        DataSource sybaseDataSource = new DataSource();
        try {
            sybaseDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver");
            sybaseDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:sybase:Tds:test.com:29812/TESTSCORE");
            sybaseDataSource.setUsername("testUser");
            String password = "user";
            sybaseDataSource.setPassword(password);
            sybaseDataSource.setInitialSize(Integer.parseInt("5"));
            sybaseDataSource.setMaxActive(Integer.parseInt("30"));
            sybaseDataSource.setMaxIdle(Integer.parseInt("2"));
            sybaseDataSource.setMinIdle(Integer.parseInt("2"));
            sybaseDataSource.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
            sybaseDataSource.setTestOnBorrow(Boolean.parseBoolean("true"));
            sybaseDataSource.setTestWhileIdle(Boolean.parseBoolean("true"));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // log.error("Exception in CoreLocalConfig.
            // NumberFormatException:"+e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // log.error("Exception in CoreLocalConfig. Exception:"+e);
        }
        return sybaseDataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory")
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.automation.entity");

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();

        //Configures the used database dialect. This allows Hibernate to create SQL
        //that is optimized for the used database.
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Sybase11Dialect");

        //Specifies the action that is invoked to the database when the Hibernate
        //SessionFactory is created or closed.
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");

        //Configures the naming strategy that is used when Hibernate creates
        //new database objects and schema elements
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy");

        //If the value of this property is true, Hibernate writes all SQL
        //statements to the console.
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");

        //If the value of this property is true, Hibernate will format the SQL
        //that is written to the console.
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Can you please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979586/nullpointerexception-thrown-by-charset-availablecharsets-due-to-our-sybase-jdbc

Answer (score 0):

i have resolved it by adding correct jconnect4.jar file into classpath